# Change in DateTime returning 0 in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My data looks like this:

```
01.02.2019 0:00
```

and it's format **Date.Month.Year** ***hours:minutes***

When I'm trying to find change in time in minutes:

```
df['DateTime']=pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'],infer_datetime_format=True,errors='coerce', format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
df['dt'] = (df['DateTime']-df['DateTime'].shift(1)).astype('timedelta64[m]')
```

Pandas returns zero values:

```
0           NaN
1           0.0
2           0.0
3           0.0
4           0.0
            ... 
14022907    0.0
14022908    0.0
14022909    0.0
14022910    0.0
14022911    0.0
Name: dt, Length: 14022912, dtype: float64
```

I had similar data but with the format **Date.Month.Year** ***hours:minutes:seconds***
I used the same approach but instead of minutes I was calculating seconds and it worked great:

```
df['DateTime']=pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'],infer_datetime_format=True,errors='coerce', format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
df['dt'] = (df['DateTime']-df['DateTime'].shift(1)).astype('timedelta64[s]')
```

What could be causing the trouble in case with minutes?

Thanks!

Comment: Tried your code with some sample data and working fine. If you can post your sample input data, maybe we can discover problem easily.

Comment: For me working perfectly.

Comment: @Parth When I open CSV file in notebook data looks like this:
CarNumber;DateTime;GPS;Speed
235;01.02.2019 0:00;88,118376 : 143,632901;51,2

and if I open in excel DateTime gives me: 01.02.2019  0:00:00

Comment: If possible, edit your answer and there post sample 4-5 rows of input data in proper format. Another possibility is that maybe your `DateTime` column has same day, hour and minute information, resulting in `0` difference.

Comment: @Parth Man, I'm really dumb... You're right, it's just first and last part of my dataframe are zeros made it look like entire data is zero..
How do I upvote you?

Comment: Okay, I have added my observation in form of answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probable Reason of problem:

Possibility is that maybe your `DateTime` column has same day, hour and minute information, resulting in 0 difference.

Check in between of dataframe and see if problem persists.

Answer (score 2):

For me in pandas 0.25.0 working your solution perfectly, but is possible simplify it by [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), get seconds by [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and divide by `60` for minutes:

```
print (df)
          DateTime
0  01.02.2019 0:00
1  01.02.2019 0:10
2  01.02.2019 0:30
3  01.02.2019 0:55

df['DateTime']=pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'],infer_datetime_format=True,
                              errors='coerce', format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")

df['dtm'] = (df['DateTime']-df['DateTime'].shift(1)).astype('timedelta64[m]')
df['dts'] = (df['DateTime']-df['DateTime'].shift(1)).astype('timedelta64[s]')

df['dtm1'] = df['DateTime'].diff().dt.total_seconds() / 60
print (df)
             DateTime   dtm     dts  dtm1
0 2019-02-01 00:00:00   NaN     NaN   NaN
1 2019-02-01 00:10:00  10.0   600.0  10.0
2 2019-02-01 00:30:00  20.0  1200.0  20.0
3 2019-02-01 00:55:00  25.0  1500.0  25.0
```

Comment: what if my time format doesn't have seconds in it?
Do I use df['dtm1'] = df['DateTime'].diff().dt.total_minutes() ?

Comment: @MDoskarin - no, `total_minutes` not exist in python/pandas, is necessary divide by `60`

Comment: @MDoskarin - If seconds not exist in datetimes, then are set default `00` like `2019-02-01 00:10:00` from `01.02.2019 0:10`